# using sed in a make-file for condtional rename

Tags: sed, makefile, gnu-make, conditional-statements

is there a way that sed can be used in a makefile to rename a generic file conditionally in a make file? Such as if I have file `generic.sh` and run a makefile that makes a `foo and bar directory`. I then want to rename `generic.sh` to `foo.sh` and `bar.sh` depending on which directory `generic.sh` is going into. I want to get started on the right path since so far I have hit dead ends.

Comment: Yes, you can used sed, but it seems like overkill. And yes, you can do things conditionally in a makefile. But it's not clear what you're trying to accomplish. You want to either `make foothings` or `make barthings` and have `foo/foo.sh` or `bar/bar.sh` appear, respectively, is that it?

Comment: the make file will make the directories `/bar` and `/foo` and I then want to copy my generic.sh into the directories but renamed to `nameofdir.sh`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a makefile that will do what you're asking:

```
all: foo/foo.sh bar/bar.sh

foo/foo.sh:
    mkdir -p foo
    cp generic.sh $@

bar/bar.sh:
    mkdir -p bar
    cp generic.sh $@
```

Crude but effective; further refinements are possible, when you're ready.

Comment: You should probably list `generic.sh` as a prerequisite for those targets.

Comment: @MadScientist: As I said, crude but effective, further refinements. Trying to keep it simple.

Comment: I get it.  I just think that without the prerequisites this makefile is pretty useless.  You might as well just write a shell script; it would only be 4 lines long.  YMMV, but I would categorize them as "bare minimum".  Cheers!

Comment: @MadScientist thank you that was very useful. I wanted a start and you provided that.